# how to run an executable remotely with psexec on multiple computers

Tags: batch-file, psexec

I'm pretty new to batch scripting.
I was looking for a simple way to start an executable on several remote computers.

What I have come up with, until now, is to make a batch file which calls psexec for all machines on the network, but it seems I can make it work for one computer only. I have two versions of the psexec part of the script:

**FIRST VERSION**

```
psexec -i  \\PC-IP -u "xxxxx" -p "yyyyy" "C:\XXXXXXXX\my_executable.exe"
```

this is the very simple instruction I thought I should use for all the machines in the network. unfortunately, it works on the first computer but then, it opens a remote cmd, as far as I understood, and I don't know how to exit from it, to go to the next psexec.

**SECOND VERSION**

```
psexec -d  \\PC-IP -u "xxxxx" -p "yyyyy" "C:\XXXXXXXX\my_executable.exe"
```

this is a variation of the first version, where I try to run the exec not interactively, so as not to be blocked and go on with the other instructions. This doesn't work, with the following error:

> Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type
> at this computer

can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

The program was actually being started, but it was "stuck" as if waiting for something, and my batch script wasn't moving forward. Turns out, the program being started on first computer wasn't listed among the current session user's running programs (i.e. from task manager, the program was listed on the "Processes" tab, but not on the "Users" tab, under the logged in user).

To actually make it run properly (in my case, my executable would open a GUI), the proper psexec command was:

```
psexec -accepteula -i 1 -d \\COMPUTER_NAME -u "COMPUTER_NAME\xxxx" -p "yyyy" "C:\xxxxxxx\my_executable.exe"
```

where "1" indicates the ID of the user "xxxx" current session.

With this the GUI showed up, the script moved on and I could execute the program everywhere on the network.

I'm still not sure why I had to add both -i and -d (I thought that either I used one, or the other).